# Whats the difference between "abc" and {"abc"} in C?

Tags: c++, pointers, string

In C specifically (i suppose this also applies to C++), what is the difference between

```
char str[4] = "abc";
char *cstr = {"abc"};
```

Problems arise when i try and pass my "abc" into a function that accepts char**

```
void f(char** s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", *s);
}
```

Doing the following yields a compiler error. If cast to char** (to make compiler happy) program seg faults.

```
f(&str);
```

However the following works fine

```
f(&cstr[0]);
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. If you can compile `f(&cstr[0])` successfully, then either `cstr` is not `char*`, or argument `s` of `f` is not `char**`. The type of expression `&cstr[0]` is `char*` (in fact, it is exactly the same as just `cstr`). Please show the actual code that causes the error. If it is this exact one, then what C++ compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of how pointers and arrays are *not* equivalent in C. In particular: **the rule that arrays decay to pointers is not applied recursively**

This means that **an array can be used as a pointer, but a pointer-to-array cannot be used as a pointer-to-pointer**. This is what you are experiencing here. This is why the compiler complains about mismatched types when you don't cast &str explicitly to char**. That should be your first clue that something is wrong.

The reason that this causes a segfault is this: The way that an array automatically decays to a pointer is by turning into the address of its first element. A pointer to an array is likewise a pointer to the address of the array's first element. So a pointer-to-array and array-as-pointer are the same thing. In other words str, when passed as a pointer, has a value identical to &str. So if you try to make &str into a pointer-to-pointer, it doesn't work, since is just a (single-level) pointer.

For example,

```
void f(char** pp);
void g(char* p);

char[] str = "abcd"; // Lets say this is allocated at address 0x1234
g(str); // Value of p in g is 0x1234 (by automatic conversion of char[4] to char*)

char* p_str = &str; // Value of p_str is 0x1234
g(p_str); // Value of p in g is again 0x1234 

f(str);  // Illegal, no conversion of char[] to char** (obvious)
f(p_str); // Illegal, no conversion of char* to char** (obvious)
f(&str); // Illegal, no conversion of char*[4] to char** (less obvious)

f((char**)p_str); // Ok, now you're overriding the typecheck
```

But after that last call to `f((char**)p_str)`, the value of pp in f is still going to be 0x1234 because you haven't modified the value of p_str, you've only suppressed the type-checker's complaint. This means that *pp is going to be 'a', not a pointer to the address that contains 'a'. And that's why you get a segfault when f tries to execute **pp.

Answer (score 10):

The first line line defines an array of four bytes. These two are equivalent:

```
char str[4] = "abc";
char str[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

The second line declares a pointer to a memory location, which contains the bytes 'a', 'b', 'c', and 0. These two are equivalent:

```
char *cstr = {"abc"};
char *cstr = "abc";
```

Your problem arises from mixing `char[]` and `char*`. If the function accepts a `char**`, you must create a `char*` to get the address of:

```
char str[4] = "abc";
char *cstr = str;
f(&cstr);
```

Comment: Well, he specifically says that `f(&cstr)` causes a segfault... though it really shouldn't. I suspect we don't have the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The braces are actually something of a false trail here.

`str` is an initialized array, not a pointer: there is no actual pointer *variable* holding the address of `str` in your example, so you cannot take its address, and thus the expression `&str` produces a compile error.

In contrast, `cstr` is a pointer variable which holds the address of a string constant, and the address of this pointer variable may be taken.

Comment: You can take an address of an array. The result is a pointer to said array. In this case, the type of such pointer would be `char(*)[4]`.

Comment: Yes Pavel, thats the compiler error that i get when using f(&str);. something like "char** does not match char(*)[4]"

Answer (score 0):

So, `&x` gets you *pointer to x*. But *pointer to array* is the same thing as *array*. This is reinforced by an exception to the lvalue expression rules,  in the case of the `&` operator, when applied to arrays, the expression type is not converted to be "pointer to ...". (6.2.2.1, ANSI 9899-1990.)

This means that `str` and `&str` are the same thing when `str` is an actual array. But `&p` where `p` is really a pointer will get you a double-indirect pointer, i.e., `**p`.

This would be a lot more clear if the standard just said "& before array is ignored", and I think dmr's publications on C used to really say that. Instead, ANSI phrases it as a conversion rule, far from the definition of the `&` operator.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try

```
char str[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

or

```
char str[4];
sprintf(str, "abc");
```

Comment: This isn't any different from `char str[4] = "abc"`. Using `sprintf` where `strcpy` would do is also a bad idea.