# How are array and pointer types handled internally in C compilers? ( int *a; vs. int a[]; )

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

I need a language lawyer with authoritative sources.

Take a look at the following test program which compiles cleanly under gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void foo(int *a) {
    a[98] = 0xFEADFACE;
}

void bar(int b[]) {
    *(b+498) = 0xFEADFACE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int a[100], b[500], *a_p;

*(a+99) = 0xDEADBEEF;
*(b+499) = *(a+99);

foo(a);
bar(b);

printf("a[98] == %X\na[99] == %X\n", a[98], a[99]);
printf("b[498] == %X\nb[499] == %X\n", b[498], b[499]);

a_p = a+98;
*a_p = 0xDEADFACE;

printf("a[98] == %X\na[99] == %X\n", a[98], a[99]);

}
```

It produces the output I expect:

```
anon@anon:~/study/test_code$ gcc arrayType.c -o arrayType
anon@anon:~/study/test_code$ ./arrayType 
a[98] == FEADFACE
a[99] == DEADBEEF
b[498] == FEADFACE
b[499] == DEADBEEF
a[98] == DEADFACE
a[99] == DEADBEEF
```

Are a and b the same type?  Is `int *a` handled as the same type as `int a[]` internally in the compiler?

From a practical point of view `int a[100], b[500], *a_p, b_a[];` all seem to be the same type.  It's hard for me to believe that the compiler is constantly *adjusting* these types in the various circumstances in my above example.  I'm happy to be *proven* wrong.

Can someone settle this question for me ***definitively and in detail*** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are a and b the same type? Is int *a handled as the same type as int a[] internally in the compiler?

From [the `comp.lang.C` FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html):

> ... whenever an array appears in an expression, the compiler implicitly generates a pointer to the array's first element, just as if the programmer had written &a[0]. (The exceptions are when the array is the operand of a sizeof or & operator, or is a string literal initializer for a character array...)
>
> ... Given an array a and pointer p, an expression of the form a[i] causes the array to decay into a pointer, following the rule above, and then to be subscripted just as would be a pointer variable in the expression p[i] (although the eventual memory accesses will be different ...

[Given declarations of](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

```
char a[] = "hello";
char *p = "world";
```

> ... when the compiler sees the expression `a[3]`, it emits code to start at the location `a`, move three past it, and fetch the character there. When it sees the expression `p[3]`, it emits code to start at the location `p`, fetch the pointer value there, add three to the pointer, and finally fetch the character pointed to. **In other words, `a[3]` is three places past (the start of) the object named `a`, while `p[3]` is three places past the object pointed to by `p`.**

Emphasis is mine.  The biggest difference seems to be that the pointer is fetched when it's a pointer, while there is no pointer to fetch if it's an array.

Comment: This quote from your link says it most concisely: "it's pointer arithmetic and array indexing [that] are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different."

Comment: It seems like arrays are more efficient as they save a memory fetch over pointers.  It seems that `a` is itself the address of 'h' whereas `p` is the address of the location containing the address of 'w'.  That's the distinction I was trying to understand.  The array `a` in that sense is actually closer to a declaration like `int a;` than to `int *a;`  Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

One of the differences - `int a[x][y]` and `int **a` are not interchangeable.

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

2.10:

> An array of arrays (i.e. a two-dimensional array in C) decays into a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

*a* and *b* are both arrays of ints. *a[0]* is not a memory location containing a memory address, it is a memory location containing an *int*.

Arrays and pointers are neither identical nor interchangeable. Arrays are **equivalent** to pointers **iff** when an lvalue of type array-of-T which appears in an expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T. This becomes clear when looking at the assembly output for related code. The three exceptions, fyi, are when the array is an operand of *sizeof* or *&* or a literal string initializer for a character array.

If you would picture this:

```
char a[] = "hello";
char *p = "world";
```

would result in data structures which could be represented like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+

   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: |  *======> | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and realize that a reference like x[3] produces different code depending on whether x is a pointer or an array. a[3] for the compiler means: start at the location a and move three past it and fetch the char there. p[3] means go to the location p, dereference the value there, move three past it and fetch the char there.

Answer (score 3):

From the [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

```
6.3.2.1.3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the 
          unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize 
          an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
          converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that 
          points to the initial element of the array object and is not 
          an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
          behavior is undefined.
```

Assume the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  char foo[10] = {0};
  char *p = foo;
  foo[0] = 'b';
  *(foo + 1) = 'a';
  strcat(foo, "t");
  printf("foo = %s, &foo = %p, &p = %p, sizeof foo = %lu, sizeof p = %lu\n", 
    foo, &foo, &p, (unsigned long) sizeof foo, (unsigned long) sizeof p);
  return 0;
}
```

foo is declared as a 10-element array of char with all elements initialized to 0. p is declared as a pointer to char and is initialized to point to foo.

In the line

```
char *p = foo;
```

the expression foo has type "10-element array of char"; since foo is not an operand of either sizeof or &, and is not a string literal being used to initialize an array, its type is implicitly converted to "pointer to char" and is set to point to the first element of the array.  This pointer value is copied to p.

In the lines

```
foo[0] = 'b';
*(foo + 1) = 'a';
```

the expression foo has type "10-element array of char"; since foo is not an operand of either sizeof or &, and is not a string literal being used to initialize an array, its type is implicitly converted to "pointer to char" and is set to point to the first element of the array. The subscript expression is interpreted as "`*(foo + 0)".

In the line

```
strcat(foo, "t");
```

foo has type "10-element array of char" and the string literal "t" has type "2-element array of char"; since neither is an operand of either sizeof or &, and while "t" is a string literal, it is not being used to initialize an array, both are implicitly converted to type "pointer to char", and the pointer values are passed to strcat().

In the line

```
  printf("foo = %s, &foo = %p, &p = %p, sizeof foo = %lu, sizeof p = %lu\n", 
    foo, &foo, &p, (unsigned long) sizeof foo, (unsigned long) sizeof p);
```

the first instance of foo is converted to a pointer to char as described above.  The second instance of foo is an operand of the & operator, so its type is *not* converted to "pointer to char", and the type of the expression "&foo" is "pointer to 10-element array of char", or "char (`*`)[10]".  Compare this with type type of the expression "&p", which is "pointer to pointer to char", or "char `**`".  The third instance of foo is an operand of the sizeof operator, so again its type is *not* converted, and sizeof returns the number of bytes allocated to the array.  Compare this with the result of sizeof p, which returns the number of bytes allocated to the pointer.

Whenever anyone tells you "an array is just a pointer", they are garbling the section from the standard quoted above.  An arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays; however, in many circumstances, you can treat an array *as though* it were a pointer and you can treat a pointer *as though* it were an array.  "p" could be substituted for "foo" in lines 6, 7, and 8.  However, they are not interchangeable as operands to sizeof or &.

**Edit**: btw, as function parameters,

```
void foo(int *a);
```

and

```
void foo(int a[]);
```

are equivalent. "a[]" is interpreted as "`*`a".  Note that this is *only* true for function parameters.

Comment: +1 You and Mark both answered different aspects of the question. If I could accept both as the answer I would, but Marks answer got more to the root of problem I was having, i.e. what's the difference in the generated code when accessing an array vs. a pointer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Spidey: Chapter and verse, please.  Per 6.7.6.3/7: "A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type* ’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to *type* ’’, where the type qualiﬁers (if any) are those speciﬁed within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with sepp2k's answer and Mark Rushakoff's comp.lang.c FAQ quote.  Let me add some important differences between the two declarations and a common trap.

1. When you define `a` as an array (in a context other than a function's argument, which is a special case) you can't write
   a = 0;
   or
   a++;
   because `a` is not an lvalue (a value that can appear on the left of an assignment operator).
2. The array definition reserves space, whereas the pointer doesn't.  Therefore, `sizeof(array)` will return the memory space needed for storing all the array's elements (for instance 10 times four bytes for an array of 10 integers on a 32-bit architecture), whereas `sizeof(pointer)` will only return the memory space required for storing that pointer (for instance 8 bytes in a 64-bit architecture).
3. When you prepend pointer or append array declarations things definitely diverge. For instance, `int **a` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer.  It can be used as a two-dimensional array (with rows of varying sizes) by allocating an array of pointers to the rows and making each one point to memory for storing integers.  To access `a[2][3]` the compiler will fetch the pointer in `a[2]` and then move three elements past the location it points to in order to access the value.  Contrast this with `b[10][20]` which is an array of 10 elements, each of which is an array of 20 integers.  To access `b[2][3]` the compiler will offset the beginning of the array's memory area by multiplying 2 by the size of 20 integers and adding the size of 3 more integers.

Finally, consider this trap.  If you have in one C file

```
int a[10];
```

and in another

```
extern int *a;
a[0] = 42;
```

the files will compile and link without an error, but the code will not do what you might expect; it will probably crash with a null pointer assignment.  The reason is that in the second file a is a pointer whose value is the contents of the first file's `a[0]`, i.e. initially 0.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

2.2:    But I heard that char a[] was identical to char *a.

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two a's and two b's in your example.

### As parameters

```
void foo(int *a) {
    a[98] = 0xFEADFACE;
}

void bar(int b[]) {
    *(b+498) = 0xFEADFACE;
}
```

a and b are of the same type: pointer to int.

### As variables

```
int *a;
int b[10];
```

aren't of the same time.  The first is a pointer, the second is an array.

### Array behavior

An array (a variable or not) is converted implicitly in most of the
contexts in a pointer to its first element.  The two contexts in C where it
is not done are as argument of sizeof and argument of `&`; in C++ there are
some more related to reference parameters and templates.

I wrote, a variable or not because the conversion is not done only for
variables, some examples:

```
int foo[10][10];
int (*bar)[10];
```

- `foo` is an array of 10 arrays of 10 ints.  In most context it will be
  converted in a pointer to its first element, of type *pointer to array of
  10 int*.
- `foo[10]` is an array of 10 int; In most context it will be
  converted in a pointer to its first element, of type *pointer to int*.
- `*bar` is an array of 10 int; In most context it will be
  converted in a pointer to its first element, of type *pointer to int*.

### Some history

In B, the direct ancestor of C, the equivalent of

```
int x[10];
```

had the effect of what in current C we'd write

```
int _x[10];
int *x = &_x;
```

ie it allocated memory and initialized a pointer to it.  Some people seem to have the misconception that it is still true in C.

In NB -- when C was no more B but not yet called C --, there was a time
were a pointer was declared

```
int x[];
```

but

```
int foo[10];
```

would have the current meaning.  The adjustment in function parameter is a
remnant of that time.

Comment: I believe `int (*bar)[10];` is pointer to an array of 10 ints and `int *bar[10];` is an array of 10 int pointer.

Comment: @Robert, right.  But I wrote about *bar and not about bar.  My goal was to show examples on the implicit conversion array->pointer to first element, not to explain C declaration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Are a and b the same type?

Yes. [Edit: I should clarify: The parameter a of function foo is the same type as the parameter b to function bar. Both are pointers to int. The local variable a in main is the same type as the local variable b in int. Both are arrays of ints (well actually they're not the same type because they don't have the same size. But both are arrays).]

> Is int *a handled as the same type as int a[] internally in the compiler?

Usually not. The exception is when you write `foo bar[]` as a parameter to a function (like you did here), it automatically becomes `foo *bar`.

When declaring non-parameter variables however there is a big difference.

```
int * a; /* pointer to int. points nowhere in paticular right now */
int b[10]; /* array of int. Memory for 10 ints has been allocated on the stack */
foo(a); /* calls foo with parameter `int*` */
foo(b); /* also calls foo with parameter `int*` because here the name b basically
           is a pointer to the first elment of the array */
```

Comment: Could you give details, sources?  Why would a compiler not handle `int *a;` and `int a[];` the same?  As far as I can tell they are *always* interchangeable;

Comment: The most important difference is that `int a[10]` reserves space for 10 ints on the stack. `int *b` only reserves space for one int pointer, so you either have to make b point to an exisiting array (or single int) or allocate memory on the heap with `malloc` and make b point to that. Another difference is that the type of `&a` is "pointer to array of ten ints" and `&b` is "pointer to int pointer". So when you add to `&a` you add an offset of `10*sizeof(int)` bytes, while adding to `&b` adds `sizeof(int*)` bytes.

Comment: `int b[10]` allocates space for 10 ints and creates a pointer to the array. `int b[]` would only create a pointer that points to nowhere, just like `int * a`.

Comment: I understand all that.  My point is that in practice `a[100], b[500], *a_p, b_a[];` are all treated as int pointers.  Specifically, they are all just a memory location containing a memory address.  Whatever notation is used to access the data you always get memory address + sizeof(int) * subscript then a dereference to get at the data.  The only difference is that a and b are effectively const pointers since the block of memory they point to can't be changed.  Other than that they're all the same.

Comment: Robert, this is C through and through.  Even with structs, all you really get is a block of memory top play with.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same!  One is a pointer to an int, the other is an array of 100 ints.  So yes, they are the same!

OK, I'll try to explain this stupidity.

*a and a[100] are basically the same for what you are doing.  But if we look in detail at the memory handling logic for the compiler, what we are saying is:

- `*a` *compiler, I need memory, but I'll tell you how much later, so chill for now!*
- `a[100]` *compiler, I need memory **now**, **and** I know I need 100, so make sure we have it!*

Both are **pointers**.  And your code can treat them the same and trample the memory near those pointers all you want.  But, `a[100]` is continuous memory from the pointer allocated at compile time while *a only allocates the pointer because it doesnt know when you are going to need the memory (run time memory nightmares).

So, ***Who Cares***, right?  Well, certain functions like `sizeof()` care.  `sizeof(a)` will return a different answer for `*a` and for `a[100]`.  And this will be different in the functions too.  In this functions case, the compiler knows the difference, so you can use this to your advantage in your code too, for loops, memcpy, etc.  Go on, try.

This is a huge question, but the answer I am giving here is this.  The compiler knows the subtle difference, and it will produce code that will look the same most times, but different when it matters.  It is up to you to find out what *a or a[100] means to the cimpiler and where it will treat it differently.  They can be effectively the same, but they are not the same.  And to make it worse, you can change the whole game by calling a function like you have.

Phew...  Is it any wonder that managed code like c# is so hot right now?!

**Edit:** *I should also add that you can do `*a_p = X`, but try to do that with one of your arrays!  Arrays work with memory just like pointers, but they can't be moved or resized.  Pointers like `*a_p` can point at different things.*

Comment: They are not both pointers. In some contexts, such as passing them to a function expecting a pointer, both are treated as pointers.

Comment: Agree.  What did I say differently?

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat into the ring for a simple explanation of this:

- An array is a series of contiguous
  storage locations for the same type
- A pointer is the address of a single storage location
- Taking the address of an array gives
  the address of (i.e a pointer to) its
  first element.
- Elements of an array can be accessed through a
  pointer to the array's first element. This
  works because the subscript operator
  [] is defined on pointers in a way
  designed to facilitate this.
- An array can be passed where a
  pointer parameter is expected, and it
  will be automatically converted into
  a pointer-to-first-element (although
  this is *not* recursive for multiple
  levels of pointers, or
  multi-dimensional arrays). Again, this is by design.

So, in many cases, the same piece of code can operate on arrays and contiguous blocks of memory that were not allocated as an array because of the intentionally special relationship between an array and a pointer to its first element. However **they are distinct types,** and they do behave differently in some circumstances, e.g. pointer-to-array is not at all the same as pointer-to-pointer.

Here's a recent SO question that touches on the pointer-to-array versus pointer-to-pointer issue: [Whats the difference between "abc" and {"abc"} in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370749/whats-the-difference-between-abc-and-abc-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer to a character array (and want to get the size of that array), you cannot use sizeof(ptr) but instead have to use strlen(ptr)+1!

Comment: Only if the character array contains a properly null-terminated string. This is not the case for every character array!